# How to move items back and forth between a TreeView and CheckedListBox?

Tags: vb.net, treeview, treenode, checkedlistbox

I've been trying to find a way to move multiple checked items from a TreeView to a CheckedListBox. I have one of each set up with dummy data and a button beneath each one to move from one container to the next. I started with the button to move from the TreeView to the CheckedListBox, but i'm having trouble with it. I get the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error for my node variable. This is what I was trying:

### Code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each node As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
        If (node.Checked) Then
            Dim name As String = node.Text.ToString
            node.Remove()
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't necessarily need to use a button to move them, I just need to be able to move multiple items at one time. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with the code?  It always helps to tell us.  And yes, you can't modify the collection when you use a for-each loop.

Comment: @LarsTech How would you go about looping through the nodes? I want to be able to see what nodes are checked and move those to the list box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the collection in a For-Each loop.  Try looping in reverse order to avoid messing up the index orders of the TreeNodes:

```
Dim movingNodes As New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = TreeView1.Nodes.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  Dim node As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes(i)
  If node.Checked Then
    movingNodes.Add(node.Text)
    node.Remove()
  End If
Next
movingNodes.Reverse()
CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(movingNodes.ToArray)
```

To move the items from the CheckedListBox back to the TreeView:

```
Dim movingNodes As New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) Then
    movingNodes.Add(CheckedListBox1.Items(i))
    CheckedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
  End If
Next
movingNodes.Reverse()
For Each s As String In movingNodes
  TreeView1.Nodes.Add(s)
Next
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, I just have one more question. I need to do something similar for going from the listbox to the treeview. Instead of "Dim node As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes(i)", How would it be written for an item of the checked list box?

Comment: @ConnorS. Updated the post.